# GTM variable in a custom HTML src attribute

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a GTM variable that works fine, but I need to add it as a value in a `src` attribute in another tag.

The variable `{{ecomm_totalvalue}}` works perfectly here:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - AdWords: xxxx --> 
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxx"></script> 
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-xxx');
</script>
<!-- Event snippet -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'page_view', {'send_to': 'AW-xxx',
    'ecomm_prodid': '{{ecomm_prodid}}',
    'ecomm_totalvalue': '{{ecomm_totalvalue}}'
  });
</script>
```

I am looking to add `{{ecomm_totalvalue}}` as a value in another Custom HTML Tag as follows:

```
<!--SECURE JAVASCRIPT PIXEL CODE START-->
<script src="https://fake.com/xxx/xxx/xxx?ext1={{ecomm_totalvalue}}" type="text/javascript" async ></script>
<!--SECURE JAVASCRIPT PIXEL CODE END-->
```

It's currently not working and I am not sure what the correct syntax would be in that `<script>`

Comment: What exactly is not working? You code tag code looks fine, however are you sure the custom variable is set to the value you expect it to be before you are referencing it in your HTML tag?

Comment: my first guess is the tags are two different scopes/triggers and you are attempting to reference `{{ecomm_totalvalue}}` either before it exists or after it is wiped.